# Open list of files using a with statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open several files from `sys.argv` inputs using a `with` statement.

I know I can do it by manually typing out each one:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test1, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as test2, \
     open(sys.argv[3], 'r') as test3, open(sys.argv[4], 'r') as test4:
    do_something()
```

But is there a way to do this without doing so, like the following pseudocode:

```
with open(sys.argv[1:4], 'r') as test1, test2, test3:
    do_something()
```

Comment: Great question! Not easily in python 2 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Python 3.3+ [with `contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(arg, 'r')) for arg in sys.arv[1:4]]
```

Amusingly, the example in the documentation is exactly what you want.

This correctly closes any open files upon exiting the `with` statement - even if something went wrong before they were all open

---

For earlier version of python, there is [a backport in the `contextlib2` package](https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=ExitStack#contextlib2.ExitStack), which you can get through `pip`

Comment: According to the documentation, I'm assuming this example still holds for contextlib2 in Python 2?

Comment: @anita: yes, it should still hold